# ios why the buttonItem not show?

Tags: ios

```
UIMapViewController *mapViewContr = [[[UIMapViewController alloc] initwithClientKey:clientKey] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nc = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapViewContr] autorelease];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *lbutton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
nc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = lbutton;
```

above codes not work, the leftBarButtonItem not show.but when i set leftBarButtonItem in function: UIMapViewController.vieDidLoad , the leftBarButtonItem show . why?
 the flowing codes is in UIMapViewController.vieDidLoad

```
    UIButton *_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
    //    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *lbutton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_button] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = lbutton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first block of code you are calling:

```
nc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = lbutton;
```

This should be:

```
mapViewContr.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = lbutton;
```

You always want to reference the `navigationItem` of the view controller, not the navigation controller.